# How to create a local copy of Oracle data to avoid query over a slow link

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a need to frequently run a large-ish query against a remote Oracle DB, which with my link speed, takes 10+ minutes. Is there a technique that I can use to create a local copy of the data  in order to improve performance?

A few notes:

- I would just need a local copy of a predetermined set of tables
- Being able to schedule an update to run nightly would be a huge bonus
- The data generally doesn't need to be refreshed throughout the day, though being able to do a delta update would be nice
- I do have remote machines that can access the data much quicker, but I'm not able to install Excel on them to perform the actual work that needs to be done (using SQL Developer is not a problem). But it would be possible to set up an auto download of the data on those machines and then create a task to copy the files to my local machine

I've considered a few ideas so far, such as configuring SQL Developer to automatically pull the data that I need and dump it to Excel (or some other format that I can use to pull the data in from another Excel file), but I thought there might be a better way.

Comment: In case you have a local DB, lookup materialized views in the doc [here for example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-read-only-materialized-views.html#GUID-7AAEC1A7-01BA-4293-AF46-F026AA2B0237)

Comment: Try this utility to dump data to csv. This script executes all sql files from the specified directory and creates separate csv files in a specified directory. https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_export_dir_tables.ps1

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the expdp and impdp tools to dump (export) only a subset of the tables :
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

But this solution could be quite hard to implement since you must have the tools on your local server and an access to the remote server to launch the export.

I think the simplest solution it to use CTAS (Create Table As Select). This will make a copy of the data from the distant server to you local server. For example if you use a database link called `DistantServer`,  issue on you local server :

```
DROP TABLE MyTable;
CREATE TABLE MyTable AS SELECT * FROM MyTable@DistantServer;
```

You can search for `Oracle CTAS` for more informations.

Then if the CTAS script is correct you can schedule it every night by creating a Oracle JOB on you local server. See `DBMS_JOB` for older release of Oracle RDBMS or better `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.